# 2.79 How do I fix the UV image editor displaying colors improperly?

Tags: uv-image-editor

Either when drawing on the UV image or the model this problem occurs.

BTW I didn't draw the square just the pink.

It doesn't always happen so when it does it is baffling. So if I make a new file for an example it may work properly other times it won't.

All new added paint shows up darker, the surrounding of the new paint is the wrong color also, it goes darker shown as the darker square. The wrong image color is only a bad display of the image editor, saving the image and opening it on a image editor displays the colors properly shown on the right side of the image.

How do I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Please tell us exactly how you're painting into the texture.. that might help us. A share of a minimal failing version of the file, with images packed, on https://blend-exchange.com/ , might help us even more.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever Blender gets wonky like this as in, only does it with this file, the cure is simple.

Copy all assets in the outliner.

Open a new empty Blender.

Paste.

This was also the cure for when some sculpt brushes quit working so I figured this might cure it as well and it did.

Answer (score 0):

It bothers me and I'm not sure how to fix it, but that's how texture-painting in blender is. A lot of times it will show the square and the color too dark as you're going, but if you want to check it, just make a little mark with the paint off to the side and then undo it. The paint should look right and the square/boxes will be gone. It's just the program.